# Re: Excel - How to create dynamic data validation list based on data table

Tags: excel, validation

I have a similar problem to one answered this past November.  (Same general title.)  The particulars of my problem are as follows:

I want to send users an excel template with validation rules.  In the first column (Receipt/Disbursement), users select whether a  record is a Receipt or Disbursement.  For that, a discrete list (Receipt, Disbursement) is defined to validate against.  This works fine.

On a subsequent column (Schedule), validation is to be based on a defined Schedule Table that references the Receipt/Disbursement column: If the user selected Receipt, a list of possible schedules from the Schedule Table is presented, if the user selected Disbursement, a different list of schedules from the Schedule Table is presented.

How do I base my validation (selection list) on the Schedule column on the result of the previously indicated Receipt/Disbursement column?

Thx!

Comment: See here: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html